# need to run python script via cron job using cpanel

Tags: python, cpanel

I need urgent help in this regard. I am trying to run a Python script via cron job on cPanel. The web hosting server is using `cPanel Version 11.30.3 (build 5)`. The cron job is set successfully and it is executing the file, but the file failed because of the following error which I recieved on email:

```
/bin/sh: /home/someuser/public_html/xml_feed/cron_job_wod.py: /usr/bin/python
: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

What I have done so far:

1. I have placed `cron_job_wod.py` under `public_html/xml_feed/cron_job_wod.py` with all permission 777 code
2. I have added this `#!/usr/bin/python` at top of my script
3. I have added `appache handler` called `cgi-script` with extensions `.cgi .py .pl`

...but still the script is not working. How could I get the right path of the Python interpreter? or what is the solution for this problem? Please help!

Comment: Try editing the shebang line to read #!/usr/bin/env python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that in the error message, there is a line break after `/usr/bin/python` and before the `:` that clarifies the message.  This suggests that the operating system is seeking the file not at `/usr/bin/python` but at `/usr/bin/python<newline>`.

Most likely, you copied the python file from a Windows system which has a style of linebreaks that `/bin/sh` is not expecting to see in your script.

You can solve this problem by converting the Windows-style newlines in the python script file with the following command.

```
dos2unix /home/someuser/public_html/xml_feed/cron_job_wod.py
```

If `dos2unix` is not available on your system, [here are a list of alternative methods](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-unix-linux-convert-dos-newlines-cr-lf-unix-text-format/) that effect the same change.

Comment: yes you are right, file is written on windows and uploaded on cpanel which is basically running on red hat linux, but how can i execute linux commands?

Comment: ok that is exact problem as you mentioned, line breaks are the problem, so what i have done i have open the file for editing via cpanel and  just save it again which converts windows line breaks to unix line breaks :) and now its working, thanks for help.